# MongoDB starts up, but commands don't respond at all

Tags: mongodb, console

Using an old 32bit machine to play w mongo.  Got it installed, starts up normally, but nothing I type in to the console does any good.

> 2015-02-24T23:45:35.996-0500 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.7
>
> 2015-02-24T23:45:35.996-0500 [initandlisten] git version: a7d57ad27c382de82e9cb93bf983a80fd9ac9899
>
> 2015-02-24T23:45:35.996-0500 [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-80-47-117 2.6.18-194.el5xen #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 22:08:06 EDT 2010 i686 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
>
> 2015-02-24T23:45:35.997-0500 [initandlisten] allocator: system
>
> 2015-02-24T23:45:35.997-0500 [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/home/Chris/data/db" } }
>
> 2015-02-24T23:45:36.040-0500 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
>   db
>
> use ccc-db
>
> db.currentOp()
>
> 2015-02-24T23:46:36.038-0500 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:53 virt:206
>
> 2015-02-24T23:46:36.038-0500 [clientcursormon]  mapped:80
>
> 2015-02-24T23:46:36.038-0500 [clientcursormon]  connections:0

I tried to connect from another machine as well and couldn't get anywhere, but really that's not surprising since I can't set up any mongo users.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you ran `mongod` and started typing commands in the same terminal window.

If you run `mongod` in a terminal simply then `mongod` spits out the loggging information on the screen. This way the mongod process will keep running until you stop it you can just press `Ctrl+C` or you close the terminal window.

You might have done something like this -

```
$ mongod --dbpath /home/Chris/data/db
```

And, then you tried to type in the commands on the same window. Remember, you need to first connect to this running mongod process through a client - mongo. Only then you can send commands to the running mongod process.

So, open another Terminal window and run the mongodb client, ie. `mongo` first.  Like this -

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
connecting to: localhost:27017/test
> use ccc-db
> db.currentOp()
```

Comment: Ah. That makes sense.  I thought I had read that mongd takes commands. Operating as both a reporting and command interface.  I must have been wrong.  Will see if I can drop mongod into a screen, and use the mongo client separately.